# c++ skipws in string?

Tags: c++, string, spaces

I know how to input a text and skip white spaces, but how about when it's a string? During the code I get a string with something like

> asdasd asdads asdasd asdasd

and so I need to remove all space in it. So is there some kind of way to write `skipws(string_text);`?

Comment: What do you mean "remove"? Do you want to construct a string with the spaces spliced out, or do you want to ignore them while iterating over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to construct a string with the value `asdasdasdadsasdasdasdasd`,  you can use the remove-erase idiom:

```
str.erase( std::remove( str.begin(), str.end(), ' ' ), str.end() );
```

or using `::isspace` from `<ctype.h>`,

```
str.erase( std::remove_if( str.begin(), str.end(), ::isspace ), str.end() );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way.  You could use find/replace in tandem to do that or you could use a `stringstream` (initialized with your input string) and use `>>` to get the words without the whitespace and concatenate the results into (another/the same) string

Comment: what replace function are you referring to?

Comment: @sehe - [std::string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) (and [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/))

Comment: @Attila That would be O(N^2).

Comment: You are right.  I guess that leaves stingstream :)  I like your approach better anyway